# does my password being intercept (http to https)

Tags: apache2

I've configured apache2 to redirect a virtual host (munin) from http to https, I've something like this:

```
cat /etc/apache2/site-enabled/default

[...]
# 20140619 - munin redirect http to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/munin/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://server1.example.com/$1 [R,L]
[...]
```

munin has its default config

```
cat /etc/apache2/site-enabled/munin

Alias /munin /var/cache/munin/www
<Directory /var/cache/munin/www>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all ::1
        Options None
        AuthUserFile /etc/munin/munin-pass
        AuthName "server1.example.com"
        AuthType Digest
        require valid-user
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault M310
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

So, when I try to connect (using chrome) to http://server1.example.com, browser immediately ask me username and password (I'm connected using http). After inserted mine credentials (browser warn me about not trusted certificate, it's ok: I don't have a trusted certficate). When I force it to connect using https I need re-insert username and password and only now I can see the munin page.

Now, when I insert user and password (the first time), does that credentials can intercepts? or I'm inside SSL tunnel?

Answer (score 1):

If credentials go over HTTP, they can be intercepted.  If credentials go over HTTPS with an untrusted certificate, they can be intercepted (if users are in the habbit of just clicking 'ok' on the warning, a bad guy can insert their own cert and defeat the whole purpose of SSL).  You're only shot at being safe is HTTPS with a trusted cert.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your reply. My question is not about intercept https. I need understand if with my configuration, when I insert for the first time my credentials, its goes via http. I'm uncertain because I need insert credential 2 times. Thanks